# Discord.js Cooldown from milliseconds to hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and making a cooldown command. And it says the time in discord in milliseconds which is way to big because its 24 hours worth. So I want display hours and minutes left over instead. Here is my code

made the code in my main.js

```
if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
    cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
}

const current_time = Date.now();
const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

if (time_stamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

    if (current_time < expiration_time) {
        const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;

        return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds before using ${command.name}`);
    }
}

time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);
```

And this is where the cool down shows how long it is.
The cooldown should be 24 hours long.

````
  name: "beg",
  aliases: [],
  cooldown: 86400,
  description: "beg for coins",
  async execute(client, message, args, Discord, profileData) {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;
    const response = await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        userID: message.author.id,
      },
      {
        $inc: {
          coins: randomNumber,
        },
      }
    );
    return message.channel.send(`${message.author.username}, you begged and received ${randomNumber} **coins**`);
  },
}; ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as what I've interpreted, you wanted a code to convert from ms to hours right? This should help you:

```js
function msToTime(duration) {
  var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100),
    seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
}
```

Let me know if there's any issue, cheers!